# two equations with curly brace

Tags: brackets

I would like to know if it is possible to make this. Basically its kind of the opposite from using the {cases} command
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE for it.

Comment: haven't tried anything because I dont really know where to begin with! Couldnt find anything similar in the forum, propably because I dont know how to search for it..:(

Comment: @Thanos In this link there is a guide of LaTeX: https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a possible solution of your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
2a &= b+1 \\
cd &= de
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\quad
\text{your text}
\qquad \left.
\begin{aligned}
5a &= b+1 \\
c+1 &= d-1
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\quad
\cdots
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to get rid of some parts and you need help, I'll be there. Don't thank me I'm here like everyone else to help you. Next time put in some evidence about what you've managed to do. Greetings. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `mathtools` package, which is an extension of `amsmath`, defines the `rcases` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{rcases}
\text{An equation}\\
\text{Another equation}
\end{rcases}
\qquad
\begin{rcases}
\text{Still another} \\
\text{And a last one}
\end{rcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]